# showing/hiding lines in matplotlib by select/deselect QStandardItemModel in PyQt4

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to showing/hiding lines in matplotlib by select/deselect QStandardItemModel in PyQt4.
But I got two questions:
1.some unknown lines show in the figure,like:

[image]
2.when I deselected the QStandardItem, the lines are still there
here is my code

```
# encoding:utf-8
import sys

from PyQt4.uic import loadUiType
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

names = ['line {}'.format(i) for i in range(7)]
Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('window.ui')

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.cp = None
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.series_list_model =QStandardItemModel()
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load)

    def fill_series_list(self):
        self.series_list_model.clear()

        for name in names:
            item = QStandardItem(name)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            self.series_list_model.appendRow(item)

        self.name_list.setModel(self.series_list_model)
        self.series_list_model.itemChanged.connect(self.check_handle)

    def load(self):
        self.fill_series_list()
        if self.cp is not None:
            self.cp.close()

        self.cp = MplLineCanvas()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.cp)

    def check_handle(self, item):
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            self.cp.show_line(str(item.text()))
        elif item.checkState() == Qt.Unchecked:
            self.cp.hide_line(str(item.text()))
        else:
            pass


class MplLineCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = {}
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        # self.axes.hold(False)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        self.set_title()        

    def set_title(self):
        self.axes.set_title("test")

    def show_line(self, name):
        line = self.lines.get(name, None)
        idx = names.index(name)
        if line is None:
            print ">>>>> line is none"
            x_list = [i for i in range(10)]
            y_list = [i*idx for i in range(10)]
            line, = self.axes.plot(x_list, y_list, lw =2.0, animated=True)
            self.lines[name] = line
        else:
            line.set_visible(True)

        self.update_lines(line)

    def hide_line(self, name):
        line = self.lines.get(name, None)

        line.set_visible(False)
        self.update_lines(line)

    def update_lines(self, line):
        self.axes.draw_artist(line)
        self.fig.canvas.update()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>571</width>
      <height>551</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>569</width>
       <height>549</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>551</width>
        <height>531</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"/>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QListView" name="name_list">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>590</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>200</width>
      <height>481</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>200</width>
      <height>16777215</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="load_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>590</x>
      <y>510</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>load</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following will do the trick.

1. Do not use `animate = True`.
2. Redraw the canvas independently of what happend inside. Use `self.fig.canvas.draw()` for updating.

Code:

```
def show_line(self, name):
    line = self.lines.get(name, None)
    idx = names.index(name)
    if line is None:
        print ">>>>> line {} (idx{}) is none".format(name, idx)
        x_list = [i for i in range(10)]
        y_list = [i*idx for i in range(10)]
        print y_list
        line, = self.axes.plot(x_list, y_list, lw =2.0) # <---- animate=False
        self.lines[name] = line
    else:
        line.set_visible(True)
    self.update_lines()                 #  <---- update

def hide_line(self, name):
    line = self.lines.get(name, None)
    line.set_visible(False)
    self.update_lines()                 #  <---- update

def update_lines(self):                 #  <---- update
    # redraw the canvas, independently of what happened to the lines
    self.fig.canvas.draw()
    self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I have another question here.If I enlarge the number of lines to 100, and let "x_list = numpy.linspace(0, 100000, 1000000)", then when I select or deselect the items, the speed of drawing will slow down.For this reason, instead of redrawing the whole figure again and again, I tried to draw the parts that are changing, so I used the method above in my code.Should you have any suggestions?Thank you! :)

Comment: The problem is that adding a new line might change the axis limits and requires a redraw of the axes as well. If you can set the axis limits a priori and not change them afterwards, a solution using `fig.canvas.update()` is equally possible.